# what happened when assigning an ip address to a network bridge?

Tags: docker, networking, ip, bridge

A network bridge transparently relays traffic between multiple network interfaces. And it is protocol independent, working at network layer 2.

However, it is common to assign an ip address to a network bridge. Docker network bridge has an ip address and it cannot work properly any more after deleting the ip address. What's more, kvm and xen also use a bridge to control network, they often  take over the network from host network interface(such as eth0) and work with an ip address assigned.

I think it is strange to use an ip address when talking about a network layer 2 appliance. What happend when assigning an ip address to a network bridge?  How a bridge works with an ip address?